# Workbook.setHidden(false) - does not display the excel workbook on GUI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have written the below code using Apache POI to create an excel workbook. I have a requirement to display the workbook whenever I am reading or writing the workbook.

I have used the function Workbook.setHidden(false), but the workbook is not opened or displayed on GUI.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
    File file = new File("c:/Syed/BatchMasterCreated.xls");     
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    
    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    workbook.setHidden(false);      

    HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet("BatchMaster");
    //Column sequence and column names
    HashMap<Integer, String> colPositionAndName = new HashMap<>();
    colPositionAndName.put(0, "TestCaseKey");
    colPositionAndName.put(1, "TestCaseOrder");
    colPositionAndName.put(2, "TestCycleKey");

    //first create the Header columns
    Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
    Cell cell;

    for (Integer colNum : colPositionAndName.keySet()) {
        cell = row.createCell(colNum);
        cell.setCellValue((String) colPositionAndName.get(colNum));         
    }
    inputStream.close();
    workbook.close();
```

[Intellisense suggest passing false as parameter to the workbook.setHidden(false) to display the workbook on GUI, but it is not working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YptBa.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YptBa.png)

Comment: What GUI are you talking about here exactly?

Comment: Note that this very likely doesn't mean "open the GUI and show the workbook" but more like "if you're displaying the workbook, show or hide the sheet". The latter is easy as this is just a flag to be checked by the UI application - the former would be way more complex and dependent on the environment (Office might not even be installed) and thus very likely not provided by POI.

Comment: Think of this as similar to setting the "executable" flag on a file: doing so doesn't directly execute the file but marks it as executable if anyone else would try to run it (separate user action).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57437072/how-to-set-the-excel-files-visibility-to-true/57439698#57439698

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS - When I say GUI, I mean the workbook should be visible or open while the code perform certain operations.

Comment: What I want to achieve is - when the code is writing something into the workbook, I want the workbook to be visible so that I can see what is being written into it during runtime.

Comment: "What I want to achieve is..." But that is not what Apache POI is made for. Apache POI tries to create Microsoft Office files without the need of an installed Microsoft Office application. Apache POI does not interact with any kind of GUI. When using Java that is what `java.awt.Desktop` is for. See linked answer in my previous comment.